# how to get cpu state in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, plc

I am new to C# and programming in general.

I have created a simple plc programme (step7), simulated on PLSIM simulator.
and i want to control this programme with a WPF Interface in C# using `Siemens S7ProSim COM Object` reference.

here is the problem:
when i want to assign the CPU State to my label, this message is shown:

> Error  1   'System.Windows.Controls.Label' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CSProject\CSProject\MainWindow.xaml.cs    32  28  CSProject
>   here is my proramm and my wpf interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CSProject
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public S7PROSIMLib.S7ProSim ps = new S7PROSIMLib.S7ProSim();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ps.Connect();
            label_CPUState.Text = ps.GetState();
            labelScanMode.Text = ps.GetScanMode().ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the `Content` property of the `Label`, not the `Text` property. `Text` is Winforms.

So, simply:

```
labelScanMode.Content = ps.GetScanMode().ToString();
```

Comment: @Yassine As a WPF newbie myself, it's one of my biggest annoyances. I'm used to almost everything having the `Text` property and now I always have to go and look up whatever the equivalent is for the appropriate control in WPF :(

Comment: @sab699 
i see, it's the same for me, but beside this, some times i don't even know that the property that i use is for winform not for wpf.
as a beginner in C# programming, i'm exposed lot of time to this problem.
thanks again.

Comment: @Yassine Unless the tutorial you're following explicitly states it's for WPF, I'd say it's probably safe to assume it's for WinForms as it's a much older technology, and as such has more tutorials written for it. You should be able to work out this sort of problem ("X type doesn't have Y property", I mean) by googling either "WPF Label Text property" or "WinForms Label Text Property" and see which one has it. Then find the correlating property for your technology.

Comment: @sab668  i agree with you, this is what happened to mee, i watched a Winform tutorial and i tried to apply it in WPF application without paying attention that there is lot of difference between winfor and WPF ! :S